# No me muestra valores de json

Tags: php, javascript, json, web

Estoy tratando de imprimir unos valores que envío por post a un script de php y me debe devolver la suma de los dos valores enviados, ya probé que el php esté recibiendo los valores y que el json este almacenando los valores.

Este es código html:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Ingreso a control de territorios</title>
  <script>
    function rresult() {
      $.post("r.php", $("#formulario").serialize(), function(resultado) {
        $("#formulario input[name=caja1]").val(resultado.caja1);
        $("#formulario input[name=caja2]").val(resultado.caja2);
        $("#formulario input[name=caja3]").val(resultado.caja3);
      }, "json");
      return false;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form method="post" name="formulario" id="formulario" onsubmit="return rresult()">
    <input type="text" name="caja1" id="caja1" value="<?php echo $caja1 ?>" />
    <input type="text" name="caja2" id="caja2" value="<?php echo $caja2 ?>" />
    <button type="submit">Enviar</button><br/>
    <input type="text" name="caja3" id="caja3" value="<?php echo $caja3 ?>" />
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

y este es el código php:

```html
<?php
$caja1 = $_POST['caja1'];
$caja2 = $_POST['caja2'];
$caja3 = $caja1 + $caja2;
echo json_encode(array("caja1"=>$caja1, "caja2"=>$caja2, "caja3"=>$caja3));
?>
```

No se que mas hacer para que pase los valores al formulario.

Comment: No entiendo exactamente cual es tu error, haz hecho un `console.log` de lo que te trae `resultado` para que puedas ver la estructura en la que te llega?

Comment: ¿Quieres _traer_ los datos **al mismo formulario** desde el cual los envías? No entiendo tu proceder.

Comment: Si quiero llevar los datos al formulario, pero al darle click al botón no me muestra nada

Comment: Se supone que cuando le doy enviar el php recibe los dos valores de las cajas de texto hace una sumatoria y reenvía 3 valores por json nuevamente en el formulario, el cual debe ubicar cada valor en su caja de texto correspondiente y en la tercera caja debe poner la sumatoria de los valores de la caja de texto

Comment: Hola alguien que me ayude por favor gracias que hace rato estoy tratando y nada que doy con el chiste

Answer (score 0):

Seguramente, el valor que está devolviendo `r.php`, aunque si es una cadena en formato [json](/questions/tagged/json) (énfasis en cadena) no es un objeto JSON. Esto puede ser porque la función `$.post()` no ha podido parsear [la respuesta en formato JSON](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) (ver campo `dataType`), y que `r.php` no tiene encabezados que indiquen que [está respondiendo en formato JSON](http://php.net/manual/es/function.header.php).

Hay dos formas de resolver este problema:

### Método 1

Podemos cambiar el archivo `r.php` para agregar un encabezado a la respuesta, estableciendo que el contenido a mostrar está en format `application/json`:

```
<?php
$caja1 = $_POST['caja1'];
$caja2 = $_POST['caja2'];
$caja3 = $caja1 + $caja2;
header('Content-Type: application/json'); // Establecer encabezado
echo json_encode(array("caja1"=>$caja1, "caja2"=>$caja2, "caja3"=>$caja3));
?>
```

### Método 2

Podemos modificar la llamada `$.post()` para agregar un parseo forzado de la respuesta de la llamada:

```js
$.post("r.php", $("#formulario").serialize(), function(resultado) {
    // Forzar el parseo de la respuesta
    if(typeof resultado !== "object") resultado = JSON.parse(resultado);

    $("#formulario input[name=caja1]").val(resultado.caja1);
    $("#formulario input[name=caja2]").val(resultado.caja2);
    $("#formulario input[name=caja3]").val(resultado.caja3);
  }, "json");
```